# How there can be $64$ triples $(x, y,z)$, made out of $4$ elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

It is stated in the book titled: Abstract Algebra, by Pierre Antoine Grillet; [on pg. 5](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=LJtyhu8-xYwC&pg=PA5&dq=example%201.7%20is%20commutative.%20associativity,%20however,%20is%20a%20different%20kettle%20of%20beans:%20the%204%20elements%20of%20example%201.7%20beget%2064%20triples%20(x,y,z),&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjg_bKF8p7tAhV-zTgGHYy8D6IQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=example%201.7%20is%20commutative.%20associativity%2C%20however%2C%20is%20a%20different%20kettle%20of%20beans%3A%20the%204%20elements%20of%20example%201.7%20beget%2064%20triples%20(x%2Cy%2Cz)%2C&f=false).

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
Example\, \, 1.7\, & a & b & c & d \\\hline
a     & a & b & c & b\\
b     & b & c & a & c\\
c     & c & a & b & a\\
d     & b & c & a & c
\end{array}$$

Example 1.7 is commutative. Associativity, however, is a different kettle of beans: the $4$ elements of Example 1.7 beget $64$ triples $(x, y,z)$, each with two products $(xy)z$ and $x (yz)$ to compare.

---

I cannot get how there can be $64$ triples $(x, y,z)$, made out of $4$ elements.

The choice of $3$ elements out of four can be done in $4$ ways:
$abc$, 
 $abd$, 
 $acd$, 
 But, from the rest only one choice is left: $b,c,d$.
So, such choices are: $4P3=4$.

Now, there need be ordering among these $3$ elements, i.e. $xyz, xzy, yxz, yzx, zxy, zyx$, leading to $6$ elements for each choice of $3$ elements.

So, the number of combinations is: $4*6=24$.

I searched for errata, but could not find anywhere for the book. So, kindly help me in

Comment: Perhaps the elements of the triple do not have to be distinct?

Comment: sampling with replacement vs sampling without replacement.  for example, (a,a,a) is considered a valid triplet.  4 choices for 1st position, 4 choices for 2nd position, 4 choices for 3rd position.  $4 \times 4 \times 4 = 64.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are four choices for each of the three entries (i.e., repetitions are allowed), then there are $4^3=64$ possibilities.  (When you calculated $4\times3\times2=24$, you assumed that the three entries had to be distinct.)

Comment: In fact, when considering operations on group elements, situations where some of the elements are the same should be included (e.g., $1+2+3 $ is just as valid as $1+2+1$)